# pythonanywhere import error "No module named flask.ext.security"

Tags: importerror, pythonanywhere, flask-security

I installed flask-security like so:

pip3.5 install --user flask-security==1.7.5

And I can see it:

```
17:14 ~/mysite $ pip3.5 freeze | grep -i flask
Flask==0.11.1
Flask-Admin==1.4.2
Flask-Babel==0.11.1
Flask-Bcrypt==0.7.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.6.0
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.1.2
Flask-Login==0.3.2
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Principal==0.4.0
Flask-RESTful==0.3.5
Flask-Script==2.0.5
Flask-Security==1.7.5
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.1
Flask-WTF==0.12
```

But log says:

```
Error running WSGI application
ImportError: No module named flask.ext.security
File "/var/www/joegillon_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
from app import app as application

File "/home/joegillon/mysite/app.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask.ext.security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Is your web app configured to run in Python 3.5? Is it using a virtualenv?